# Поместить в байтовый слайс содержимое другого слайса между индексами 0 и 5

Tags: golang

Ломаю голову, не знаю как поместить в байтовый слайс `buf` по индексу между 0 и 5.

Вот код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    word := "hell"
    buf := make([]byte, len(word)+2)
    buf[0] = 5
    buf[len(buf)-1] = 10

    for i, w := range buf {
        switch w {
            case '\r': fmt.Println("Bad character")
            case '\n': fmt.Println("Bad character")
            default:
                if i == 0 || i == (len(buf)-1) {
                    continue
                } else {
                    buf[i] = word[i]
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылка на playground: https://play.golang.org/p/SvNopXlg_P2

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [`copy`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy):

```golang
a := []byte{'a', 'A'}
b := []byte{'b', 'B', 'c'}
copy(b[0:2], a[0:2])
fmt.Printf("%s", b)
// Output:
//   aAc
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uCWpfN0wa4V.